# Unable to Connect to Oracle DB via server explorer in visual studio

Tags: .net, oracle, visual-studio, oracle10g

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB from my Visual Studio through server explorer but getting error "ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified" (screenshot attached) on the other hand when adding connection string to app.config its working fine.

[Error Popup while connecting Oracle Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtdA.png)

Comment: Please don't put pictures, write down the error message. Also provide information about which driver do you use.

Comment: Please, provide more information about how are you trying to connect. That message is just telling you "the information you passed me to connect to the database is wrong".

Comment: I'm not using any driver I'm simply connecting by using Oracle DataAccess Library

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: I have connected by using connection string and now I have to connect my visual studio to oracle DB but while doing this it showing me this error